# BibTeX bibliography suddenly broken

Tags: bibtex

My sample document looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Demo Bibtex}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some claim \cite{velikonja2015asymmetric}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

My bib file (`References.bib`) is located in the same folder and looks like this:

```
@article{velikonja2015asymmetric,
title={On asymmetric shape of electric double layer capacitance curve},
author={Velikonja, Alja{\v{z}} and Kralj-Igli{\v{c}}, Veronika and 
Igli{\v{c}}, Ale{\v{s}}},
journal={Int. J. Electrochem. Sci},
volume={10},
pages={1--7},
year={2015}
}
```

The resulting document looks broken:

[image]

Like everything in it is counted twice. Help much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I simply use class `apa` instead of `article` I can compile the code and bib entry without error message.

Try the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to get a compiling MWE with TeX code and bib file):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{velikonja2015asymmetric,
  title={On asymmetric shape of electric double layer capacitance curve},
  author={Velikonja, Alja{\v{z}} and Kralj-Igli{\v{c}}, Veronika and 
          Igli{\v{c}}, Ale{\v{s}}},
  journal={Int. J. Electrochem. Sci},
  volume={10},
  pages={1--7},
  year={2015}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{apa} % article

\title{Demo Bibtex}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some claim \cite{velikonja2015asymmetric}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

## EDIT:

With class `report` and `biblatex` with `biber`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{velikonja2015asymmetric,
  title={On asymmetric shape of electric double layer capacitance curve},
  author={Velikonja, Alja{\v{z}} and Kralj-Igli{\v{c}}, Veronika and 
          Igli{\v{c}}, Ale{\v{s}}},
  journal={Int. J. Electrochem. Sci},
  volume={10},
  pages={1--7},
  year={2015},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{report} % article

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style = authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{Demo Bibtex}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some claim \cite{velikonja2015asymmetric}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result with biblatex]

Comment: Thank you, that made the error go away, but now the References title is a different size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am pretty new to the BibTeX environment. I am not submitting to the `apa` journal, but rather working on a thesis that requires me to use a very similar style to the `apacite`, but not quite. I was hoping I could customize it a little from `apacite`. Do you have any clues as to what the simplest way would be? Thanks again.

Comment: "Votes by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."